# Can't load zurb foundation javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

*Edit*

I decided to use `twitter-bootstrap-rails` instead, I don't need a answer.

*Edit end*

I want to use `zurb-foundation` tab function in my rails project, but it doesn't working like this image.

[image: foundation tab not working]

It looks like javascript is not loaded, but I couldn't find out the reason.

I added two lines in `Gemfile`.

```
gem 'compass-rails'
gem "foundation-rails"
```

And `bundle install`, then `rails g foundation:install`.

`app/assets/javascripts/application.js` have lines like this.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation
//= require_tree .

$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });
```

and `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` is like this.

```
 /*
 *= require_self
 *= require foundation_and_overrides
 *= require foundation
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

I copied and pasted sample html code from foundation web page.

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<dl class="tabs">
  <dd class="active"><a href="#simple1">Simple Tab 1</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="#simple2">Simple Tab 2</a></dd>
  <dd class="hide-for-small"><a href="#simple3">Simple Tab 3</a></dd>
</dl>
<ul class="tabs-content">
  <li class="active" id="simple1Tab">This is simple tab 1s content. Pretty neat, huh?</li>
  <li id="simple2Tab">This is simple tab 2s content. Now you see it!</li>
  <li id="simple3Tab">This is simple tab 3s content.</li>
</ul>
```

`rails server` log indicates that foundation javascript is properly loaded.

```
Started GET "/assets/foundation.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-21 06:20:31 +0900
Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-21 06:20:31 +0900
Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-21 06:20:31 +0900
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-21 06:20:32 +0900
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.abide.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-21 06:20:32 +0900
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.accordion.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-21 06:20:32 +0900
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.alert.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-21 06:20:32 +0900
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.clearing.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-21 06:20:32 +0900
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.dropdown.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-21 06:20:32 +0900
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.interchange.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-21 06:20:32 +0900
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.joyride.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-21 06:20:32 +0900
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.magellan.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-21 06:20:32 +0900
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.offcanvas.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-21 06:20:32 +0900
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.orbit.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-21 06:20:32 +0900
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.reveal.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-21 06:20:32 +0900
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.slider.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-21 06:20:32 +0900
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.tab.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-21 06:20:32 +0900
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.tooltip.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-21 06:20:32 +0900
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.topbar.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-21 06:20:32 +0900
Started GET "/assets/foundation.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-21 06:20:32 +0900
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.equalizer.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-21 06:20:32 +0900
```

I checked console log by developer tool in chrome, but there was no error recorded.

What else can I do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 4):

As per the shared code, I don't see the details of `application.css` file. For the `zurb-foundation` css to work, you would need to add the following in your `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` file:

```
*= require foundation
```

**UPDATE**

As per the update in the question for `application.css`.

1. First you need to rename `application.css` to `application.css.scss`.
2. Then in `foundation_and_overrides.scss` add the following directive at the top.

   ```
   @import "foundation";
   ```
3. Assuming that `foundation_and_overrides.scss` exists in `app/assets/stylesheets` folder, you don't need to require it in `application.css.scss`. So, `application.css.scss` should only have

   ```
   *= require_self
   *= require_tree .
   ```

Also, you can see the details in **[Zurb Foundation Documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/applications.html)**

Comment: Thanks for heads up, but I already have the line in `application.css`. I added detail to my question.